# Phonegap on Android: load images

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I load images from the internet and use them in the listview. When I launch my app in desktop browser, image loads fast and goes to the listview item. BUT on the device image loads slower and by the moment it is loaded is somehow doesn't go to listview item.

```
 function onLoad() {
    //console.log("init");
    loadImage();
}

function loadImage() {

    $.getJSON(websiteUrl, function(data) {
        imageUrl = data[0]["image"];
        console.log( imageUrl );
        document.getElementById("view_1").src = imageUrl;
    });

}

body onload="onLoad();" 
//some markup here
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" class="content-primary">

            <li><a href="index.html">
            <img id="view_1" src="" />
            <h3>Broken Bells</h3>
            <p>Broken Bells</p>
            </a></li>

        </ul>
```

Also I noticed that "deviceready" event fires after onLoad. My question is - what is the very first init function in Phonegap app where I could start loading images **before** html body is loaded?